# How to stop stderr output from gcloud command in cron script without stopping all error output?

Tags: stderr

I have a bash script for a cron job that uses Google Cloud SDK's `gcloud` command after some conditional statements.

eg.

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules update allow-ssh --source-ranges=$(echo "${mylocations[@]}" | tr ' ' ',')
```

It is run using `crontab` like this:

```
*/2 * * * *        /home/user/bin/firewall-update.sh >/dev/null
```

I have an email MTA set up, so I can get emails regarding any errors from the server, but stdout is redirected to `/dev/null`.

The problem is that gcloud output goes to stderr, even when run successfully, so I always get an email with these sort of line whenever the script is run.

> TITLE: Cron user@host /home/user/bin/firewall-update.sh >/dev/null
>
> Updated
> [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/project-name-4234534/global/firewalls/allow-ssh].
>
> Updated
> [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/project-name-4234534/global/firewalls/allow-mosh].
>
> ...

I have tried adding `--verbosity=error`, `critical` and `none`to the gcloud commands, but they have no effect.

Why does the output go to stderr when it completes successfully and how can I stop getting these emails, while still getting them when there is an error?

Comment: Capture stderr and only print it if the exit status isn't 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add this global flag, which applies to all gcloud commands:

```
--no-user-output-enabled

    Print user intended output to the console. 
    Overrides the default core/user_output_enabled property value for this command invocation. 
    Use --no-user-output-enabled to disable.
```

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference#--user-output-enabled

Actual errors are still directed to stderr.